# My nodemcu esp8266 is heating a lot and the on board LED of gpio16 is On continuously. What's the Reason of heating?

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, electronics, iot, voltage-protection

**How it happened**

Recently I was working on a device with **Blynk** application in which my device will burn crackers using Blynk. I wanted to create a safe environment for burning crackers. There was a dilemma to power Nodemcu with a battery first I used a **38650 lion battery** but it didn't provide sufficient power to Nodemcu. Than I connected two 38650 battery in series than it was working fine for half a minute. But later it started became hot but than I removed the power supply immediately and powered it with **3.3v charger** than also it was heating and still.

**My research**

I researched a lot and also changed the **S4 didode** with **IN4007** but it is still heating and malfunctioning. I **checked** all the parts but they were **not shorted**. What's the problem with my Nodemcu why is it heating and not working properly.
**With regards**
**Naman**

Comment: heating is caused by too much current being drawn

Comment: what do you have connected to the nodemcu? ... how is it conected?

Comment: 1. How did you connect the batteries? 2. What else is connected to the NodeMCU? 3. Where exactly (which component) does the heat come from?

Comment: Ok so my Nodemcu is connected with RELAY of 5v the heat is coming from the microcontroller.

Comment: And can you answer question 1? How did you connect the batteries?

Comment: What is the output voltage of your Lion batteries? The Nodemcu is a 3.3V device. It's voltage regulator needs an input voltage of  7V - 12V, based on the searching I did. If your batteries put out ≈10V then 2 of them in series is too much for the input of the NodeMCU's voltage regulator.

Comment: In series both batteries took out 7

Comment: Volt and 4000 mah

Comment: Is it too much ??